# create email id for registered users in Drupal 7 and Nginx

Tags: 7, emails

I am working on a `Drupal 7` site which lets users to register using their email, when the user verifies their email address, I am planning to create new email address for them to use, which has extensions as my domain.

Suppose my Domain is `http://abcd.com` When `Mr. X YZ` register and verify his registration he will automatically get new email address from me as `x.yz@abcd.com`.

How do I accomplish this with `Drupal` ? Can this be done via `server-side` if so then I have `Nginx` server, do I need `SMPT {}` Block for that ?

I was thinking to ask users to use `google mail service` to login to their email address provided by me. Still, not sure how to accomplish that one as well.

I feel I am really missing something, as I was searching around, there were few suggestions about `Postfix` but I really don't know what it is, and how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nginx won't help you. It can act as a mail proxy. But you need an MTA: Sendmail, Postfix to create a new mail account on your domain. Take a look here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273163/how-can-create-email-id-using-shell-exec-or-exec-in-php

You will require root permissions.

Comment: I felt so, now I have to install `Postfix` and make it work with Drupal !!!